# Difference between "detection method" vs "detecting method"

Tags: gerunds, ing

I'm not a native speaker of English. So, I don't know English Grammar well.

## What's difference between "detection method" vs "detecting method"?

Which one is correct?

Is it related to

I'm writing this sentence "This paper proposes an automated intersection detecting method."

The intersection means cross road on the map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think either one works, but you need a hyphen between *intersection* and either *detecting* or *detention*.

Personally, I don't like the sound of *intersection detection method* (because of the successive *-tion*s), so I would go with

> This paper proposes an automated intersection-detecting method.

Answer (score 0):

I think *detection method* is what you want here. *detecting* is a verb, so would apply in the case of *the instrument is detecting  a gas leak*.

Comment: "Detecting" is a verb form, the present participle of "detect."  Participles have verb-like qualities (e.g., they can take objects) but they don't act as predicates.  In this case of "detecting method," the word "detecting" acts as an adjective, modifying "method."  Consider "laughing gas," which is a type of anesthetic, not an amused gas.

Answer (score 0):

Technically intersection detection method works.

Intersection detecting method is obviously a gerund phrase fitting nominally as a direct object of the term proposes. Automated is a participle being used to describe such a method. The term automated creates the idea that this method will actively be "detecting" intersections on a map, so I'd go w/detecting method.